# WordPress warning: preg_match(): Compilation failed: nothing to repeat at offset 1

Tags: regex, wordpress, preg-match

Suddenly my friend's WordPress based website started showing up this warning on subpages:

> Warning: preg_match(): Compilation failed: nothing to repeat at offset
>   1 in /wp-includes/class-wp.php on line 218

Lines 218/219 that are returned in the warning are as follows:

```
if ( preg_match("#^$match#", $request_match, $matches) ||
     preg_match("#^$match#", urldecode($request_match), $matches) ) {
```

Seems like the code is responsible for URL reworking.

Any ideas what could possibly be going wrong?

Comment: Probably, it should be `"#^" . preg_quote($match, "#") . "#"`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew It actually stops displaying warning but also "Page not found" pops out

Comment: What does `$match` contain?

Comment: @revo ?p=15538-2(?:/([0-9]+))?/?$

Comment: Do you have changed your permalink structure recently?

Comment: @wp78de not really, however its been set to custom /$postname Forever, any possibility this stopped workingafter some recent update?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The error does not appear on the homepage but on sub-pages. Thus, I guess the permalinks structure is corrupt. An often suggested fix goes like this:

1. temporary disable all your plugins! Do not skip this step.
2. go to the WordPress admin dashboard: Settings -> Permalinks 
   note what you have in the custom permalinks field somewhere else
3. temporary switch to default permalinks. Save settings.
4. check the page in question: are the `preg_match` errors gone?
5. switch back to your previous custom permalinks setting
6. re-enable back all the plugins, the pages should be back to normal.

Comment: This made me find the answer finally! Thanks! The problem was in corrupted permalinks structure as you said, the custom structure `/$postname` should have been written like that: `/$postname$/`. I will remain your answer as the top one instead of posting actual solution to my particular problem because it's the debugging method provided by you that actually made me get to conclusion. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I had this very same issue and it was driving me crazy!

It was a simple fix for me, hopefully will be for anyone else who has the same issue!

All I had to do was login to the backend of the site with /wp-admin and then go to Settings > Permalinks and then set it to 'Post Name' and then click 'Save Changes'. Hard refresh the page/s you had the issue on and it might just be resolved.